# GLSL: Why is a random write in local array significantly slower than a looped write?

Tags: performance, glsl, gpu, compiler-optimization

Lets look at a simplified example function in GLSL:

```
void foo() {
    vec2 localData[16];
    // ...
    int i = ... // somehow dependent on dynamic data (not known at compile time)
    localData[i] = x; // THE IMPORTANT LINE
}
```

It writes some value `x` to a dynamic determined index in a local array.
Now, replacing the line `localData[i] = x;` with

```
for( int j = 0; j < 16; ++j )
    if( i == j )
        localData[j] = x;
```

makes the code **significantly** faster. In several tested examples (different shaders) the execution time almost halved and there were much more things going on than this write.

For example: in an order-independent transparency shader which, among other things, fetches 16 texels the timings are `39ms` with the direct write and `23ms` with the looped write. Nothing else changed!

The test hardware is an GTX1080. The assembly returned by `glGetProgramBinary` is still too high-level. It contains one line in the first case and a loop+if surrounding an identical line in the second.

- **Why does this performance issue happen?**
- **Is this true for all vendors?**

---

Guess: `localData` is stored in 8 vec4 registers (the assembly does not say anything about that). Further I assume, that registers cannot be addressed with an index. If both are true, than the final binary must use some branch construct. The loop variant might be unrolled and result in a `switch`-like pattern which is faster. But is that common for all vendors? Why can't the compiler use *whatever results* from the `for` loop as the default for such writes?

Comment: See also https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/688607-glsl-shader-slow-when-having-too-big-arrays/5342183/ (about having big array declared within the shader)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further experiments have shown that the reason is **the use of a different memory type for the array**. The (unrolled) looped variant uses registers, while the random access variant switches to *local memory*.

*Local memory* is usual placed in the global one, but private to each thread. It is likely that accesses to this local array are going to be cached (L2?).

---

The experiments to verify this reasoning were the following:

1. Manual versions of unrolled loops (measured in an insertion sort with 16 elements over 1M pixels):

   Base line: `localData[i] = x`   33ms
   For loop: `for j + if i=j`  16.8ms
   Switch: `switch(i) { case 0: localData[0] ...`: 16.92ms
   If else tree (splitting in halves): 16.92ms
   If list (plain manual unrolled): 16.8ms

   => All kinds of branch constructs result in more or less the same timings. So it is not a bad branching behavior as initially guessed.
2. Multiple vs. one vs no random access (32 element insertion sort)

   2x `localData[i] = x` 47ms
   1x `localData[i] = x` 45ms
   0x `localData[i] = x` 16ms

   => As long as there is at least one random access the performance will be bad. This means there is a global decision changing the behavior of `localData` -- most likely the use of a different memory. Using more than one random access does not make things worse much, because of caching.